# SSRS report to email subscription only when there is data

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I currently have a report that grabs certain orders (orders with discounts) and is emailed on a daily basis. However, is there a way so that it will only email or send out the subscription, if there are orders with discounts?

Help would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround we use for this problem is kind of silly, but very effective.

Add a row count check at the beginning of your code like:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(X) FROM TABLES)>0
BEGIN
RAISERROR ('No Rows to Report',2,1)
END
```

The error will halt execution of the subscription.

Comment: When you say beginning of the code do you mean beginning of my Select Statement?

Comment: Yes.  You want to get a count of the rows your query is going to return prior to executing the query for the report.  You are essentially running the query twice.